# sys.getrefcount() returns value much higher than 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference, pass-by-reference

I understand that calling `getrefcount()` copies reference by value into the function's argument, temporarily bumping up the object's reference count. This is where the second reference comes from.

However, when I run the following code I am getting reference count value of `33`

```
import sys
a1 = 5
print(sys.getrefcount(a1))
```

I was expecting an output of `2` but it is printing `33`

Comment: 5 is a very common number. It's not surprising there might be other references to it kicking around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`5` is one of the small integers CPython caches. Every value that happens to be `5` thus points to the same instance. Change it to, for example, `a1 = 5000` and you'll see it print `2` as expected.

Comment: By making `a = 5000` I am getting `4` now

Comment: Are you sure you're not adding any other references to that object? If I only change `5` to `5000` in your original code, I get `2`.

Comment: @meallhour You will probably see a difference between running it interactively and putting it into a script. Probably there are references in the compiled module - I'm not sure about the details.